# Mongo data base

Tags: mongodb

Can't find my data base path in mongoDB.

I really need to know where my data is stored on my Mac OSX 10.7

And when I change my DBpath it keeps telling me that DBpath is not defined. (I am using homebrew)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By default mongo configurations are stored on the following path.

> /etc/mongod.conf

You can find the dbpath in the following file. By default it is :

> /data/db or c:\data\db

You can change the dbpath using the following command

> mongod --dbpath /data/newpath

Comment: FYI .. `/etc/mongodb.conf` only applies as a convention for the [packaged Linux installs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) which include init scripts that use this conf file.  Different package managers, such as Brew, may have their own conventions.  `mongod` only looks for a config file if provided as a command line [`--config` argument](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the dbpath used by running the following command in the mongo JS shell:

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
```

Look for a parsed setting for "dbpath".

Comment: I checked the [homebrew MongoDB formula](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb) and it looks like brew's default data path should be `/var/mongodb` if you are using the default LaunchAgent configuration.